# Ruby - Using nil parameters to support different types of an class

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, say I have a class called `Song`. I would like to know how correcty to write the `initialize` so that it supports 2 different types of. For example:

`song_full = Song.new(fromSomeCloudStorage)`

`song_preview = Song.new(fromLocalStorage)`

Then say I have a Song class, where I always want to assign the `@time_stamp`, but then depending on whether there is `cloud_storage` or not, assign `@cloud_store_spec`

```
def initialize(cloud_storage = nil, time_stamp = nil, local_storage = nil)
    @time_stamp = time_stamp || (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i.to_s
    @cloud_store_spec = cloud_storage
end
```

I'm thinking of using `nil` as I have done, however would the code know which is `cloud_storage` and which is `local_storage`. Is it actually possible?

Any help appreciated?

Comment: What about `initialize(storage, time_stamp = nil)` with `storage` being an instance of either `LocalStorage` or `CloudStorage`, each a sub-classes of a generic `Storage` class? This way, `Song` just have to know how to work with `Storage` in general and the sub-classes do the actual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use keyword arguments to allow you to pass the relevant data to the initializer (up to you if you want to include `time_stamp` as a keyword or regular arg):

```
def initialize(cloud_storage: nil, local_storage: nil, time_stamp: nil)
  @time_stamp = time_stamp || (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i.to_s
  @cloud_store_spec = cloud_storage
end
```

This will make things a lot clearer when calling the class, allowing:

```
song_full = Song.new(cloud_storage: fromSomeCloudStorage)
song_preview = Song.new(local_storage: fromLocalStorage)
```

In terms of how your code will know whether the code is from cloud or local, if you mean the class's instances, you can just check for the presence of `@cloud_store_spec`, something like:

```
def cloud_storage?
  @cloud_store_spec.present?
end
```

Then, from anywhere else in your code, you can call:

```
song_full = Song.new(cloud_storage: fromSomeCloudStorage)
song_full.cloud_storage? # => true

song_preview = Song.new(local_storage: fromLocalStorage)
song_preview.cloud_storage? # => false
```

Hope that helps and I'm reading you right :) Let me know how you get on or if you've any questions.

---

**Update for Ruby 1.9.3**

As keyword arguments were introduced in Ruby 2.0, for 1.9.3 you can use an options hash:

```
def initialize(options = {}) # again, timestamp can be a separate arg if you'd prefer
  @time_stamp = options[:time_stamp] || (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i.to_s
  @cloud_store_spec = options[:cloud_storage]
end
```

The rest of the code will remain the same.

Comment: Sweet - thats great, I never knew of that semicolon parameter annotation. I'm actually using an old version of Ruby too 1.9.3 - presume its supported there.

Comment: Great, glad it helps! Keyword args were introduced in 2.0 IIRC - give me two mins and I'll update the answer with a way you can use in 1.9.3 :)

Comment: Have popped in the update @userMod2. Let me know whether it's all working for you, and feel free to accept the answer if so.

Comment: Ah, so even when doing `def initialize(options = {})` I can still do `song_preview = Song.new(local_storage: fromLocalStorage)`

Comment: Yep - you can provide an unwrapped hash as the final arg to any method call in Ruby, meaning the above equates to `Song.new({ local_storage: fromLocalStorage })`. The same applies were you providing additional arguments - no need to wrap them.

Comment: Re the one line method, Ruby style guides always suggest splitting over multiple lines. You _could_ use `attr_reader :cloud_store_spec`, which would allow for `Song.new(...).cloud_store_spec` to be called, but I feel the named method is much more readable IMO. If you're not using it, it's worth installing [RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) for your IDE - it's great at giving advice for bits like this.

Comment: Ah I like that `attr_reader :cloud_store_spec` style as well. Then I presume I set with something like `Song.new.cloud_store_spec(fromSomeCloudStorage)`
Is this the Ruby standards preferred way?

Comment: Close :) You can use [`attr_accessor`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor), which would make available `Song.new.cloud_store_spec` and `Song.new.cloud_store_spec=`. Personally, I'd lean towards the approach in my answer as it's clear, readable and easy to maintain, though I hope there's something in here to get you where you need to be!

Answer (score 0):

If CloudStorage or LocalStorage can be considered as classes:

```
class LocalStorage
  def initialize; p 'LocalStorage class initialized'; end
end

class CloudStorage
  def initialize; p 'CloudStorage class initialized'; end
  def play; p "...playing song"; end
end
```

Maybe you could consider to hard code a Hash, (let apart time_stamp):

```
class Song
  attr_reader :store_spec

  def initialize(kind = nil)
    storage_kind = {cloud: CloudStorage, preview: LocalStorage}
    @store_spec = storage_kind[kind].new
  end

  def storage_kind
    @store_spec.class
  end

  def play
    @store_spec.play
  end
end
```

So you can call for example:

```
song = Song.new(:cloud) #=> "CloudStorage class initialized"
song.storage_kind #=> CloudStorage
song.play #=> "...playing song"
```